# How to pass an ID to the Controller without using hidden form field?

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

Let's suppose I have the following form and I want to post a comment to a thread on a forum:

```
<form action="{{ route('post.store') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <label>Response
        <textarea name="content"></textarea>
    <label>
    <button>Post Response</button>
</form>
```

In order to associate this post with thread I'm replying to, I'd also want to pass along the ID of the thread I'm replying to. I can do this with a hidden input field like so:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{{ $thread->id }}">
```

My issue with this is that the user can edit the value of the ID, and end up submitting the response to some other thread on the forum. I know this is a bit of a nit-picky issue, but it's not something I want the user to be able to do.

How else can I pass this ID to the controller method to store the post? Can I pass it over via session data, or perhaps there's another way I'm just overlooking.

**Also I don't believe this is an authorization issue: authenticated users are authorized to reply to these posts** - if there's a way I can use authorization to my advantage I'd love to know but I just don't see it being solved like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### tl;dr

You could store the actual thread ID in a temporary session variable or a cookie.

---

I think you are going about solving this problem incorrectly, you shouldn't need to worry about what the user enters, rather you should be worrying about how to deal with what the user enters. Your code should be ready to handle any such bypass attempt and as such, you should be setting up correct validation / sanitization instead of following the philosophy of ["security through obscurity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity).

Generally, you check if the user is allowed you perform [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) actions on the thread in question before doing any other validation.

You also mention:

> My issue with this is that the user can edit the value of the ID, and end up submitting the response to some other thread on the forum.

quite frankly, as long as they aren't performing CRUD actions that they shouldn't be able to, I don't see an issue. Truthfully, I don't really see it as *my* problem (as the developer) as the user will be typing out a reply and posting it to a complete different thread.